# Angularjs Select doesn't seem to update ng-model when option chosen

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have two SELECTs on a page. They both load the possible options correctly and the ng-model appears to set properly as the initial value is set based on values in the model when loaded. I want to be able to make sure that the user does not choose a value for both of the SELECTs so I added a function for the ng-click. Inside the function I check if one was initially set that the other model does not now have a value. The problem I am facing is that when I get into the function, the models don't appear to be reflecting what the user has chosen.

I looked at a lot of questions on here and found solutions that indicated that the ng-options probably needed some changes. I have tried what I have seen, but nothing seems to be helping.

Here are the two HTML SELECTs

```
<select ng-model="example3model" class="form-control input-md" ng-click="checkTags(3)" ng-options="industry as industry.text group by industry.group for industry in industryData track by industry.id" >
    <option value="">-- Select Industry --</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="example4model" class="form-control input-md" ng-click="checkTags(4)" ng-options="product as product.text  group by product.group for product in productData track by product.id" >
    <option value="">-- Select Product --</option>
</select>
```

Both arrays (industryData and productData) look similar (different actual values) and look like this:

```
industrydata is an array of about 28 objects like these 3...

{group: "Energy and Natural Resources", id: "5", text: "Chemicals"}
{group: "Consumer Industries", id: "6", text: "Consumer Products"}
{group: "Public Services", id: "7", text: "Defense Security"}
```

If I look at the model of one of the selects if initially set with values it looks like: (this is for an 'example4model'

```
Object
  group : "Finance"
  id    : "34"
  text  : "Governance, Risk, and Compliance"
```

My function snippet looks like this:

```
    $scope.checkTags = function(curModel) {

    if (curModel == 3) {
        if ($scope.example4model != null && $scope.example4model.text != '' && $scope.example3model != null) {
            $rootScope.showMsg("Remove Product before adding an Industry.");
            $scope.example3model = null;
        }
    } else {
        if ($scope.example3model != null && $scope.example3model.text != '' && $scope.example4model != null) {
            $rootScope.showMsg("Remove Industry before adding a Product.");
            $scope.example4model = null;
        }
    }

};
```

If example4model is set initially, and I try to choose a value from the example3model select, I would think when I come into the function, I should see some value in example3model, but it is null. If I change the option chosen for example4model, when I come into the function, it shows the initial value and not the newly selected one.

It seems that somehow the model is not being updated to show the chosen options but I can't figure out why. Based on responses to other questions, I added the 'as' clause and the 'track by' clauses but that didn't help either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I drew up a sample of your provided snippets in Plunker (bottom of post)...

Have you tried initializing your models with `null`?

What may be causing the issue on your end (if I understand the issue correctly) is that your models will be `undefined` before being set using the `<select>`. And in your `checkTags()` method, you are checking for "not null".

I suggest declaring your models in your controller like so:

```
$scope.example3model = null;
$scope.example4model = null;
```

This should allow your `checkTags()` if statements to catch the model values before being set. Alternatively, you can change your if statements to check for whether the model is "undefined" instead.

### Other Recommendations

- I also might recommend changing `ng-click` to `ng-change` -- ng-click will fire your `checkTags()` function whenever the `<select>` is clicked whereas ng-change just fires it when an option is selected.
- In your `checkTags()` if statements, you can null check with a simple `if($scope.example3model)` -- check my snippet for those (line 43).
- Don't forget to use `!==` when you are checking a value and looking for a truthy / falsy (bool) evaluation.

### Plunker

https://embed.plnkr.co/mUgsqY/

Wrap `checkTags()` in a $timeout:

```
// In your HTML
<select ng-model="example3model" ng-click="initiateCheckTags(3)">
    <option value="">-- Select Industry --</option>
</select>

// In your Controller
$scope.initiateCheckTags = function(curModel) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.checkTags(curModel);
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: thank you. I actually do have them set to null and then load them from tables - if they have them. I should've showed that, sorry...forgot it when I posted snippets.  I had tried the ng-change and same thing happened - doesn't seem like value is present - but I will try again, since that was before I used the "as" and "track by" parts.

Comment: changed to ng-change and same thing occurred...when I check the values in the checkTags they do not show what was just chosen...the screen does show the newly chosen values.

Comment: That's pretty strange -- the DOM is updated with the selected / correct value from your model, but the ng-change / ng-click function `checkTags()` doesn't register them...?  if you console.log() the models at the top of `checkTags()` (like I have in the Plunker), what is the output that you are seeing?

Comment: if no value was initially set, then it is null...if there was a value, then there it shows the initial value and not anything chosen. I agree it is pretty strange...it's like it's not talking to anything. I'm thinking of wasting too much more time, to try something else. I have tried so many things already...

Comment: I may be wrong, but it sounds like it's either a variable reference issue or something is blocking the digest cycle... If you call `$scope.$apply()` at the top of `checkTags()` or wrap the `checkTags()` in a `$timeout` function, does it yield a different result?

Comment: if I wrap it, how would I do that? (sorry, never did it before). Meanwhile I will try the apply....

Comment: if I call $scope.$apply()...I get errors saying: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress....

Comment: Ahh, okay. So I'm not sure how your application / controller is set up, but the use of `$rootScope` somewhere is triggering a digest cycle. Your controller model variables aren't updated while that cycle is running because they are in a different scope. You'll either need to handle your $rootScope calls in another manner (like, try testing `checkTags()` without using `$rootScope.showMsg()` and see what you get) or wrap `checkTags()` in a timeout -- too long for a comment, so added an example at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: thanks. I tried your example for the timeout() and still no luck. I also tried instead of setting the example3/4 models to null to make them set as example3/4model = {group: "", id: "", text : ""} just to see if it would change anything...it didn't. I am thinking you are right in that it is something with the scope...I'll keep looking....thank you.

Comment: Darn. Sorry for not being able to better help on this one. Good luck!

Comment: so I tried last night using ng-dropdown-multiselect to create the drop downs and they pretty much worked right away. I am still trying to figure out how to use the event call backs to only fire when I change the value (and not all the time) to do the checking if both are set, but at least when I make a selection it is showing in the model.